# Li-po battery: determining compatibility for replacement battery and charger

Tags: lipo, substitution

I want to find substitute batteries for a pair of heated boots (heating element in the boot sole) with larger battery capacity for longer operating time. The boots came with two 8 V, 2600 mAh batteries (one for each boot) and I am hoping to find batteries with 5000-10000 mAh that will be safely compatible with these boots.

The manufacturer does not offer a battery with larger capacity, and of course they say that I should not use a battery from a different manufacturer. Is it possible to safely substitute the batteries, or is that always a bad idea? And how I would find the substitute?

Here are the specs printed on the battery and charger that came with the boots:

- Rate: 7 V
- Capacity: 7.7 V, 2600 mAh, 20.20 Wh
- Input: 8.7 V, 1.2 A
- Output: 6-8.7 V, 2.5 A max.
- Charger input: 100-240 V AC, 50/60 Hz, 0.5 A
- Charger output: 8.7 V, 1.2 A

And here are specs from a possible 7500 mAh substitute from a different manufacturer. It has the same 2.5 mm pin connectors. The numbers are very close, but not exactly the same. Would this battery work (safely) with my boots? Would it work (safely) with the existing charger? If not, how should I go about finding a compatible battery?

- 7.4 V, 7500 mAh
- 7.4 V/5 V Dual Voltage Output Li-po battery
- Capacity: 7500 mAh, 57.75 Wh
- DC input: 8.7 V, 2 A max.
- DC output: 7.4 V, 2 A
- USB output: 5 V, 2.4 A

Charger for the substitute battery (I would not buy this charger if the one I already have would work safely):

- Charger input: 100-240 V AC, 50/60 Hz, 0.5 A
- Charger output: 8.7 V, 1.0 A

Comment: Welcome! EE top tip: H = henry (unit of inductance) and h = hour.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it will be better if you put the specifications of the boots as well. it will be hard to say what kind of battery will work without knowing about the consumption capacity of the device.